# How can I use d.IsNewResource() when importing a resource in Terraform?

Tags: terraform

Context: I'm writing a Terraform Provider

A typical [pattern](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/issues/16796) (#1) in resource implementations in the `Create/CreateContext` function is to return the `Read/ReadContext` function at the end to fill in the Terraform State for all attributes.

Another typical pattern (#2) in resource implementations in the `Read/ReadContext` function is to remove the resource from the Terraform State if the remote system returns an error or status that indicates the remote resource no longer exists by explicitly calling `d.SetId("")` and returning no error. If the remote system is not strongly read-after-write consistent (eventually consistent), this means the resource creation can return no error and also return no resource state.

[Official HashiCorp's tutorial](https://learn.hashicorp.com/tutorials/terraform/provider-setup?in=terraform/providers) supports #2 pattern:

> When you create something in Terraform but delete it manually,
> Terraform should gracefully handle it. If the API returns an error
> when the resource doesn't exist, the read function should check to see
> if the resource is available first. If the resource isn't available,
> the function should set the ID to an empty string so Terraform
> "destroys" the resource in state. The following code snippet is an
> example of how this can be implemented; you do not need to add this to
> your configuration for this tutorial.

```
if resourceDoesntExist {
  d.SetID("")
  return
}
```

Here's a minimal working code sample that displays usage of both #1 and #2 patterns:

```
func resourceServiceThingCreate(d *schema.ResourceData, meta interface{}) error {
    /* ... */

    return resourceServiceThingRead(d, meta)
}

func resourceServiceThingRead(d *schema.ResourceData, meta interface{}) error {
    /* ... */

    output, err := conn.DescribeServiceThing(input)

    if !d.IsNewResource() && ErrCodeEquals(err, 404) {
        log.Printf("[WARN] {Service} {Thing} (%s) not found, removing from state", d.Id())
        d.SetId("")
        return nil
    }

    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("error reading {Service} {Thing} (%s): %w", d.Id(), err)
    }

    /* ... */
}
```

**The problem is** when I add an importer to the resource using

```
Importer: &schema.ResourceImporter{
    StateContext: schema.ImportStatePassthroughContext,
},
```

that basically calls `resourceServiceThingRead(d, meta)` and if `conn.DescribeServiceThing(input)` returns `404` (e.g., there was a typo and the user used wrong ID that caused `404` status code) TF provider will print no errors:

```
terraform import resource_foo.example-2 foo-1234 
resource_foo.example-2: Importing from ID "foo-1234"...
resource_foo.example-2: Import prepared!
  Prepared resource_foo for import
resource_foo.example-2: Refreshing state... [id=foo-1234]

Import successful!

# but the client actually received 404 error that it ignored
```

since

```
if !d.IsNewResource() && ErrCodeEquals(err, 404) {
        log.Printf("[WARN] {Service} {Thing} (%s) not found, removing from state", d.Id())
        d.SetId("")
        // print out no error and confuse a user
        return nil
    }
// instead of going here
if err != nil { // print out & return descriptive error }
```

piece of code will be executed. Is there a way to mark imported resource as new or something so I'd be able to print out the real `404` error for a failed attempt of importing a resource?

Otherwise it looks like we'll have to remove `schema.ImportStatePassthroughContext` and use copy pasted `resourceServiceThingRead_2()` that excludes `d.SetId("")` check to support showing descriptive `404` errors for imports.

Comment: I am not completely sure, but I think you maybe want to use `resourceServiceThingtateRefreshFunc` that returns a `resource.StateRefreshFunc`. This would update the state independent of the `read` function. I think also some providers use different errors thrown from their bindings depending upon how the resource is read from the endpoint. You could code to behave differently depending upon the thrown error, which would be different between a read with a state `id` or with the value for the `import`.

Comment: > This would update the state independent of the read function -- how would this function be able to fill in other attributes based on just ID I use in an import if it doesn't use *read function? A code pointer would be helpful here.